# Do something based on result of CompletableFuture without blocking thread in Java

Tags: java

First off, I am not really familiar with CompletableFuture. What I am trying to do is retrieve data from a database via CompletableFuture and then do something with the result. Using CompletableFuture#join/get to work with the data is blocking the thread.

```
CompletableFuture<IPlayerData> future = playerDataManager.getOfflinePlayerDataAsync(target);
IPlayerData result = future.join(); //blocks the thread e.G. if database isn't reachable
//work with the result (maybe callback?)
```

Note that I am trying to not run the part of code above on a seperate thread. Is there any good way to do this non-blocking? I am pretty sure that there is something wrong with my code (Maybe getOfflinePlayerAsync?) and I really don't know how to continue.

```
@Override
  public CompletableFuture<IPlayerData> getOfflinePlayerDataAsync(OfflinePlayer player) {
    CompletableFuture<IPlayerData> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    DiscoBox.schedule(() -> future.complete(handler.loadObject(player.getUniqueId().toString()))).createAsyncTask(); //gets object from database
    return future;
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at `CompletableFuture`: it has methods like `whenComplete(BiConsumer<T, Throwable>)` or `thenRun(Runnable)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to block the thread that is "receiving" the value, you could do one if the following:

```
// Get the value if it is available
if (future.isDone()) {
     value = future.get();
     // do something with value
}

// Get the value if it is available in the next second
try {
    value = future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // do something with  value
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    // ho hum
}
```

With a `CompletableFuture`, there other non-blocking alternatives; e.g.

```
value = future.getNow(someDefault);
if (value != someDefault) {
     // do something with value
}
```

Note with all of the above, you are only making one attempt to get the value.  If one attempt is not enough you might be tempted to do something like this:

```
while (!future.isDone()) {
     // do something else
}
value = future.get();
// do something with value
```

but this potentially blocks the thread ... in effect.  You don't get to move past the end of the above code until the future has been completed.

If you don't care when the value is available because you don't intend to do anything with it, you can simply ignore the `future`.

Finally, the other way to deliver values asynchronously is using callbacks.  You could provide a callback function as a parameter to your `getOfflinePlayerDataAsync` method.  Then you could deliver the result like this:

```
    DiscoBox.schedule(() -> callback(handler.loadObject(...))).createAsyncTask();
```

The callback might simply assigned the returned value to some shared variable, or it could do something more complicated.  The key thing is that it will execute on the async task's thread, not on the thread that calls `getOfflinePlayerDataAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This has really helped me. :)